# How to stop and refresh custom command in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I have a custom command with an infinite loop, which I plan to run on either supervisord or via an authenticated HTTP request. It's something like the following.

```
public function handle()
{
    $delay = $this->option('delay') ? (int) $this->option('delay') : 5;
    $config = Cache::get('app_settings');
    $this->info("Running every $delay seconds");

    while (true) {
        $this->info('Config check '.$config['state']);
        $this->info("Request done, sleeping for $delay seconds");
        
        sleep($delay);
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I stop it if I run the command calling `Artisan` class via HTTP request?
2. If the command is running, how do I refresh/reload the command to pull the changes from the code update? Much like how `queue:restart` works. Because when the command is running and I re-write/update on the cache, it's pulling; it's not reflecting on the command output.

Comment: second question is your command code not updated?

Comment: first question is you need single thread runnin?

Comment: Why you not using scheduler?